# Suggested BigData DB for Collecting social network analytics

Tags: hbase, bigdata

I would like to build a system, that collects social networks data, every hour, and samples what is going on on specific shares/posts (there could be thousands).
Once I do the crawling, I want to save it in a big data db which I can analyze later on.

The analyzing process could potentially be Spark or even application code analysis.
This means I am looking for the best DB that will allow me to:
1. Query.
2. Spark and other commonly used data processing can be used on top of it.

Which one would you suggest? HBase? MongoDB? Couchbase? BigTable? DynamoDB?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you want to store hourly social network data to this nosql db in a "batch" fashion and use the db to drive predominantly analytics. If that is the  use case, then I would definitely look at Apache Phoenix/HBase. In HBase, you can import data in a batch fashion very efficiently. Using Phoenix on top of HBase, you get SQL like interface. Would you also be using this DB to do random reads (single row reads rather than sequential)?. Cassandra is another option to look at. Cassandra and Couchbase are similar in features. Other factors include Cloud / On Premise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention spark, and i think you need to store GBs of data for a day and this input data never changes (read-only) i recommend storing your raw data in files, like s3 or hdfs. Because reading from file as json will be faster than reading from any database and your spark job will be same whether it is from hdfs or hbase or couchbase. File storage will be cheaper also.

If you still want to store them in hbase, it does not provide much sql query functionality even you use phoenix, hbase is a key value db and you would end up with many secondary index tables and duplicate data, which is unnecessary for this kind of batch use case.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra was designed to implement a combination of Amazon's Dynamo distributed storage and replication techniques combined with Google's Bigtable data and storage engine model
Twitter and Facebook use Cassandra.

For full text search use Solr.